# Login problem In Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, login

In my phone I have already signed in Stack Exchange site but it is always asking me that You haven't joined this site please join again.

Moreover when I clicked join site. I am not being allowed to do anything and then again the whole process goes into recursion.

Screenshots:

> [image: Image Reference]
>
> [image: Image Reference]

Please do something.

- App Version: 1.0.93
- Device Manufacturer: LENOVO
- Device Model: Lenovo A6020a40
- OS Version: 5.1.1 (A6020a40_S034_160923_ROW)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed as of version 1.0.94 going live as we speak.

The apps use a cached version of the [`/sites`](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites) API route. When you attempted to interact with a post on Stack Overflow, which now has a `site_url` starting with `https://`, we were checking your network users against that stale cache.

As of version 1.0.94 the first time that cache is being read each app session, we check to see if there are pre-https migration URLs and force update if needed.